# Square root of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, block-matrices

Given the $2n \times 2n $ matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{A} & A^* \\
A^* & \bar{A}
\end{pmatrix}$$

let $X$ the matrix such that $XX=A$, that is $X=\sqrt{A}.$

So $$X=\begin{pmatrix} 
X_{1,1}&X_{1,2}\\
X_{2,1}&X_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
How can i show that $X_{1,2} X_{1,1} =  X_{1,1}X_{1,2}$, that is that the matrices commutes?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}$Multiplying
two block-wise [centrosymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrosymmetric_matrix) matrices yields
$$\eqalign{
\m{A&B\\B&A}\cdot\m{X&Y\\Y&X} &= \m{(AX+BY)&(AY+BX)\\(BX+AY)&(BY+AX)} \\
}$$
Since matrix addition commutes
$\big({\rm i.e.}\;(BX+AY) = (AY+BX)\big)$
the product is also block-wise centrosymmetric. Therefore any *integer power* of such a matrix maintains the symmetry. And any *function* of such a matrix (assuming it can written as a convergent power series) exhibits the same symmetry.